# How to fix outbound Twilio Website to Mobile VOIP Calls not making a ringing sound for the caller?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

We have a javascript twilio webpage that calls either a classic phone number or attempts to make a VOIP call to a mobile app using twilio.

When a call is made to a standard phone, the website user can hear a ringing sound as one would expect.  However when the call is routed to a VOIP user, then twilio is just silent while the mobile app that is being called is in a ringing state.  This freaks out the users who think the website has failed, when really its just waiting for the mobile app user to answer.

While there are many different ways to implement this, what is the simpliest twilio implementation to play a ringing sound while waiting for a voip user to pick up?

Note: everything works normally from the mobile app user's end, to them the phone is ringing, its the caller who is not getting a ringing sound.  I want the ringing sound to stop when the mobile user has picked up and I don't want to hold up the call to play the ringing sound.

How do I duplicate the ringing effect of calling a regular phone number when I'm calling a voip user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently [Voip call](https://www.fcc.gov/general/voice-over-internet-protocol-voip)s do not appear on their own to make a normal ringing sound, unlike classic non-voip calls.  So one has to provide their own ringing UI effects or sound.

I used the [ringing event](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/connection#onringing-handlerhasearlymedia) on the [`Twilio.Connection` object](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/connection) that is generated from a properly configured [`Twilio.Device` object](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/device#twilio-device).   The connection object will not normally emit a a ringing event. But if the `enableRingingState` configuration parameter is set to `true` when creating the `Twilio.Device` object, the `Twilio.Connection` object will emit the event.

I use that event to kick off a ringing recording using an [`<Audio>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) without the `controls` attribute and with the `loop` attribute. I made a recording of a regular phone call's ringing sound to play, so that it sounds the same.  Then when the call connects, I shut off the ringing sound.  Also if `hasEarlyMedia` is set to true then I also do not play the ringing sound, since maybe whatever that early media is will play.  I haven't yet observed that case, however.

I detect ahead of time if I'm going to making a voip call rather than a standard call, so that I don't create a double ringing effect.  Regular (non-voip) phone calls provide their own ringing sound.